# R - How to remove duplicate strings from a character vector

Tags: r

How can I remove duplicate strings from a character vector in R?

`original <- c("hi hi there", "hello you", "you good you good")`

`desired <- c("hi there", "hello you", "you good")`

Thanks

Comment: You can use regex for recursive matching. Would you consider "you good you" to be a duplicate, or only when the repeated words are adjacent to each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the `stringr` package for this:

```
 library(stringr)
 library(dplyr)

 sapply(original, stringr::str_split, " ") %>% 
          lapply(unique) %>% 
          lapply(paste, collapse = " ") %>%
          unlist() %>% 
          unname()
 # Output 
 #      "hi there"       "hello you"        "you good"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine with reshaping your character vector to a data frame structure:

```
library(tidytext)
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(original = c("hi hi there", "hello you", "you good you good"),
                 id       = 1:3) %>%
  unnest_tokens(output = "split_words",
                input = original,
                token = "words") %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  distinct(split_words, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
  summarize(desired = paste0(split_words, collapse = " "))
```

which gives:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
     id desired  
  <int> <chr>    
1     1 hi there 
2     2 hello you
3     3 you good
```

Note: if you need a character vector you can add `%>% pull(desired)` to the code above.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very nice problem, i found a baseR solution :

```
# 0: the problem:
original <- c("hi hi there", "hello you", "you good you good")
desired <- c("hi there", "hello you", "you good")

# 1; create this function
foo <- function(x) {
  x<-strsplit(x,split = " ")
  x<-unique(unlist(x),use.names=F)
  x<-paste(x,collapse = " ")
  return(x)
}
# 3: lapply function 
out<-lapply(original, foo)
# 4: unlist the output
des<-unlist(out)
# 5: test
>all.equal(des, desired)
[1] TRUE
```